# What is the proper way to seed the big system's database with sample data when using .NET Core with EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The system is created in a .NET Core with Entity Framework and SQL Server. It's quite big at the moment and it's still growing. In the continuous delivery pipeline, there are many environments e.g.

```
test1 -> test2 -> test3 -> test4 -> preprod -> prod
```

Each environment can have different configurations e.g. it can be hosted in Azure, on-premise or in an external private cloud.

There is a need to seed the database with sample data for each of those environments but each environment very often needs to have a different set of data.

I can see two approaches:

1. Write SQL scripts.

   The advantage is that SQL scripts can be run very easily from SSMS or some other console window. The disadvantage I see is it can be horrendous to maintain when the system growths.

   I'm thinking about finding the relations and management of Ids.
2. Create seeder classes in C# which can be run via EF Core.

   This solution allows me to create classes which can be easily maintained and in theory I can create some feature toggle which tells which seeder class should be run for a given environment.

   If the DB schema changes very often it would require to update all the SQL seeding scripts. The script can become invalid which cannot be automatically detected like in case of using the EF core seeding mechanism.

   I've spoken to one developer who told me that it's a bit scary to run automatically such seeder class every time I make a release in the CD pipeline and the Seeder classes for test environments shouldn't be added to the Code Repository.

The question is what is the proper approach and can I use the Entity Framework for the described problem? Cheers

Comment: How did you implement the second option? Do you use `EF Core` to seed the data with model class, or run `sql scripts` from `EF Core`? It's unclear what you mean by `The script can become invalid which cannot be automatically detected like in case of using the EF core seeding mechanism`. No matter which approaches you select, you will need to change the sql scripts or C# seeder when you change your models. I would recommend you try the second, share us how you implement the second operation, and what is your unsatisfied.

Comment: The second option is a pure C# implementation. There is nothing to do with sql.

Comment: Example: If you add a SQL script to the solution e.g. `INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] (Id, Blah) VALUES ('4','foo');` and then you decide to remove or rename the field `Blah` in your database model, the Visual Studio won't complain that there is something wrong with the SQL script.

Comment: Not sure how can i minimize such a big problem to a small demonstrable example in code.. maybe tell me what you don't understand in my question so i can try to better explain it.

Comment: If its pure C#, what is the relationship between `SQL script` and `the Visual Studio won't complain that there is something wrong with the SQL script`?

Comment: because I need to store the SQL seeder scripts somewhere so I added them to the source files of my project.

Comment: For the second option, what is the purpose for sql script?

Comment: sry maybe there is a misunderstanding here. For the 2nd option, there are no SQL scripts just pure c#.

Comment: What is the limation for the second option?

Comment: Maybe the speed. The seeding by EF can be slower than running SQL script. In my case, I'm thinking about let's say 70 tables and each table can have up to 50records.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirements and size of db. In my previous projects we have created SQL scripts but may not be well suited for a continuously changing dB. You can also use data generators such as:

https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-generate.aspx

https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/